# Can we name a relation mapping in typeorm/hibernate so that when the error is thrown, it makes more sense while reading/understaning it?

Tags: hibernate, typeorm

I have two entities `user` and `student` and there is a `onetoone` mapping between the two - `student` depending on `user`. When I try to create a record in student which doesn't have a mapping record in `user`, it gives an error like below -

```
[Nest] 4040   - 06/28/2020, 4:06:36 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] insert or update on table "student" violates foreign key constraint "FK_8231416aa588b99afce55d26032" +130ms
QueryFailedError: insert or update on table "student" violates foreign key constraint "FK_8231416aa588b99afce55d26032"
```

I was wondering if it's possible to name the `onetoone` relation in the entity so that this error becomes more meanningful, something like - `UserNameFKContraint` instead of `FK_8231416aa588b99afce55d26032`.

This is what I have in entity -

```
@OneToOne(() => User, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'userName',
    referencedColumnName: 'userName',
  })
  user: User;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Delete the table and annotate the `OneToOne` with the following.

```
@ForeignKey(name="your_constraint_name")
```

Basically if you are letting the JPA to create the tables, you can customise the table name, column name, foreign key column names, join table name if used, any contraint names

Comment: Where exactly? Like `@ForeignKey(name="your_constraint_name")@OneToOne(() => User, { nullable: false })` ?

Comment: Yes. Just above your `@OneToOne` annotation.

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna try it in a while as data will be gone. Need to test something before that.

Comment: Seems, this annotation isn't present in `typeorm`. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: It may bw like this in typeorm `@JoinColumn({ 
    constraintName: 'fk_post_author_id'
  })`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be fitting in. Wonder if they have it or not.

Comment: Alternatively if they dont support it, spring boot easily allows to provide a schema.sql. First enable the `show.sql` in your spring boot application, copy all the generated ddl statements and then change the constraint name and use it schema.sql

Comment: Okays. Thanks a bunch. Will try it out.